# Посоветуйте бесплатный видеоплеер для размещения на ХТМЛ-странице

Tags: javascript, html

Нужен видеоплеер для размещения на хтмл-странице.
Для создания видеоинструкции. Человек скачивает
архив с видео и страницей, и смотрит в оффлайне.

Comment: а что мешает человеку скачать видеофайл и смотреть его без хтмл-страницы?..

Comment: @deivan подозреваю что параллельно с видео будет давать текст с полезной информацией )

Comment: текст параллельно с видео называется - субтитры :)

Comment: ivsevolod, вы совершенно правы. Будет ссылочка на сайт с полезной информацией :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте этот [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) (html5)